# Nodejs server only listens on localhost

Tags: node.js, virtualbox

I created two virtual machines - One is Windows 7 and the other is RedHat 6.4. I am trying to run the simplest server on the RedHat machine and then access it from the Windows 7 machine. The problem is that I can't seem to make it work!

This is my code (Simplest there is) :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
```

Tried to listen(8080,"0.0.0.0" and "127.0.0.1"). Both didn't work.

When I try to access with from the RedHat machine with "wget" command it works, but when I try to go to the Windows 7 machine and enter from chrome or even with "telnet IP 8080" it doesn't work.

Both machines have access to the internet and I can also ping from each to other meaning there is connection between the two.

Also I added the port to the iptables in RedHat and I think I allowed it in the firewall aswell. Just added a new rule that allows all ports.

I wanted to add that I also made a Windows Server 2008 machine and I tried to run the node server there and connect to it from my Windows 7 machine, But still the same problem exactly! Can connect from the Windows Server machine but not from any other machine.

Comment: Are you sure you ping the right computer ? And isn't there a firewall ? In anycase, this looks more like a question for superuser or serverfault, I don't think your JS program is at fault.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the RedHat I also added the port to the iptables and I think I enabled the port in firewall. I just made a new rule that allows all ports. - I just read this somewhere : "This resolution is program-specific. You need to bind the program's listener to the right interface by name{eth0, or something like that), IP address(192.168.1.99, or something like that), or the MAC address. This depends on the program." And I couldn't find how to do that.

Comment: Try with `.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0')` or `.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')`

Comment: Already tried both, still didn't work.

Comment: Theoretically it's either loopbacking the localhost, which should have been resolved with listening on `0.0.0.0`, so the next thing I can think about is an IP firewall that might automatically block some ports. Try `sudo ipfw add allow tcp from any to any 8080`

Comment: Is there anything I need to do to be able to use ipfw? because I can't use it and didn't really find anything from a quick search of the web about it. btw I just added something I did to my question - please look at it.